# How to update mock store in Redux to test generated number of <li>s in component?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am working on a simple react-redux app to get familiar to react-redux testing and I have an app with a textarea & two buttons. 
Submit comment button adds a comment from a textarea to a list and fetch comments button adds to the list comments coming from fake jsonplaceholder API.

What I want to achieve:
I am simulating a click event, mocking a fake get API call and then I would like somehow probably to update the store if I am not mistaken so as comments are populated & lis are generated eventually during the test.

Here is what I have tried so far:

integration.test.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import Root from 'Root'
import App from 'components/App'
import axios from 'axios'
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter'
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'

const mock = new MockAdapter(axios)

const mockStore = configureMockStore()
// const store = mockStore({})
let wrapped, store

beforeEach(() => {
    wrapped = mount(
        <Root initialState={store}>
            <App />
        </Root>
    )
})

afterEach(() => {
})

it('can fetch a list of comments and display them', () => {


    wrapped.find('.fetch-comments').simulate('click')

    mock.onGet('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments').reply(200, {
        comments: [{ name: 'Fetched #1' }, { name: 'Fetched #2' }]
    })

    axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments')
        .then(response => {
            store = response.data.comments
            console.log(store)
            wrapped.update()
            console.log(wrapped.find('li').length)
            expect(wrapped.find('li').length).toEqual(2)
        })
})
```

I created a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/094n2ojn) to reproduce the issue and to give a better idea of what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it seems that there was no need to use a mock redux store for some reason although someone would expect that making a fake API call would demand to update a fake store by passing the fake fetched data as `props.comments` in this particular case. Using moxios and `done` to `it's function` as an argument and `done()` after what is expected gives the desired example.

```
import React from "react";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import moxios from "moxios";
import Root from "../Root";
import App from "../components/App";
    
beforeEach(() => {
      moxios.install();
      moxios.stubRequest("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments", {
        status: 200,
        response: [{ name: "Fetched #1" }, { name: "Fetched #2" }]
      });
});
    
afterEach(() => {
   moxios.uninstall();
});
    
it("can fetch a list of comments and display them", done => {
   const wrapped = mount(
       <Root>
         <App />
       </Root>
   );
    
   wrapped.find(".fetch-comments").simulate("click");
    
   moxios.wait(() => {
        let request = moxios.requests.mostRecent();
        request
          .respondWith({
            status: 200,
            response: [
              {
                name: "Fetched #1"
              },
              {
                name: "Fetched #2"
              }
            ]
          })
          .then(() => {
            wrapped.update();
            console.log(wrapped.html());
            expect(wrapped.find("li").length).toEqual(2);
            done();
            wrapped.unmount();
          });
      });
 });
```

I also updated the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/094n2ojn) in case someone wants to see the example.